# Insert Euro and Dollar symbol to a column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 rows which looks like this.
[image: table]
 This is the create statement of the table.

```
CREATE TABLE `currency` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Abbreviation` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `symbol` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
```

And all I want to do is insert symbols for them, but its not working.
I tried doing it this way.

```
insert into currency (id, symbol ) values (1,'€') ;
insert into currency (id, symbol ) values (2,'$') ;
```

Comment: you can see this, it is inserting symbols: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d787d/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UPDATE` with a `WHERE` condition.

```
UPDATE currency
SET symbol = '€'
WHERE ID = 1;
UPDATE currency
SET symbol = '$'
WHERE ID = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert all the columns:

```
insert into currency(id, name, description, symbol )
    select 1, 'EUR', 'Euro', '€' union all
    select 2, 'USD', 'United States Dollar', '$';
```

You have columns that are declared `NOT NULL` with no default values.  These need to be assigned a value.